# Can we say "too little explored method"?

Tags: phrase-request

Can we say **"too little explored method"**?

What other alternatives do we have?
I'm limited by the word number, so the less the better.

Comment: I suggest that you add some context. It will help people who answer the question

Comment: Are you writing an introduction for a scientific paper or something?

Comment: @nodakai something... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "too little" might work with other phrases, but it doesn't seem so nice with this one.

I like

> virtually unexplored method

You could be emphatic and simply say

> unexplored method

Depending on the context,

1. untested method
2. unproved method
3. unexamined method

could work.

Comment: What about «relatively unexplored method»?

Comment: I think in English, we only use  the " quotation marks. Sure, "relatively" could work too.

Comment: Sure. Good luck.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I figured out the one I was really thinking of. Maybe you can consider "insufficiently explored method".

Answer (score 1):

We would expect to see it this way, with **too little explored** appended as a fused modifier:

> ... is a method too little explored.

Answer (score 1):

Place a hyphen between "too" and "little" and you'll be good to go.

Incorrect: "a too little explored method"

Correct:   "a too-little explored method"

However, like another user stated, "a virtually unexplored method" would be a more common construction.

Comment: What's the reason for the hyphen?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the structure you need a proper adverb, for example

> a not sufficiently explored method

Comment: "An insufficiently explored method" is more idiomatic than "a not sufficiently explored method".